# To get rid of "double lines"

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following code:

```
p0 = {2, 0, 0};
p1 = {3, 0, 0};
p2 = {2, 1, 0};
p3 = {2, 0, 1};
p4 = {3, 1, 1};
Graphics3D[{PointSize[.02], Point[{p0, p1, p2, p3, p4}]}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

with the following output:

[image]

It seems that, in addition to the axes, Mathematica draws a box containing the axes **and** a bit more. So, I get three "double lines". How can I get rid of this doubling? I would just like the three edges of the box to go right along the three axes (and I would like to have the box).

Comment: Add `Boxed -> False`

Comment: Add `PlotRangePadding -> None` to keep the Box.

Comment: @MelaGo : Thank you for commenting. However, I wanted to keep the box.

Comment: @Xacobeo2002 : Thank you for your comment. If you care to make it a formal answer, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica by default adds a little bit of padding when it comes to PlotRange. Setting `PlotRangePadding -> None` should do the trick.

[image]